# 502 bad gateway errors when using ALB and aws-load-balancer-controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, aws-application-load-balancer

We have a service on our EKS cluster, this service is an API that receives many thousands of requests per day. Occasionally, we have noticed when making a request we get a 502 error. If i were to guess out of 100 requests maybe 10-to-20 would be 502 errors.

We are using aws load balancer controller - https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller

**example response**

```
    status: 502,
    statusText: 'Bad Gateway',
    headers: {
      server: 'awselb/2.0',
      date: 'Wed, 06 Oct 2021 10:24:19 GMT',
      'content-type': 'text/html',
      'content-length': '122',
      connection: 'close'
    },
```

**Troubleshooting**

1. The service is not crashing and does not receive the requests being made ( which return 502, we can identify this using correlation-ids sent from the client to the service).
2. When port-forwarding to bypass the alb and make a direct connection requests to the service we do not experience this problem.

From the above we have determined that these 502's are not from our application/service.

---

Upon further research we have noticed others experiencing a similar issue to ours.

- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/976
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/989

**Environment**

- AWS Load Balancer controller version: `v2.1.3`
- Kubernetes version: `1.19`
- Using EKS (yes/no), if so version?: `Yes/v1.19.13-eks-8df270`

**Please see configuration details below:**

Service Deployment Config

```
kubectl get service --selector=app=entity-extractor-api-staging -n staging
NAME                           TYPE       CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
entity-extractor-api-staging   NodePort   172.20.95.5   <none>        80:31037/TCP   18h

kubectl get deployment --selector=app=entity-extractor-api-staging -n staging
NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
entity-extractor-api-staging   1/1     1            1           18h
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: entity-extractor-api-staging
  labels:
    app: entity-extractor-api-staging
  namespace: staging
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: entity-extractor-api-staging
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: entity-extractor-api-staging
  labels:
    app: entity-extractor-api-staging
  namespace: staging
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: entity-extractor-api-staging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: entity-extractor-api-staging
        log-label: 'true'
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: entity-extractor-api-staging
        image: <redacted>:$TAG
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env: <redacted>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
      nodeSelector:
        acme/node-type: worker
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: staging-ingress
  namespace: staging
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "<redacted>"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP":80,"HTTPS": 443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:<redacted>:certificate/0250a551-8971-468d-a483-cad28f890463,arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:<redacted>:certificate/b32e9708-7aeb-495b-87b1-8532a2592eeb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/tags: Environment=prod,Team=dev
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /health
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-interval-seconds: '300'
    # alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: access_logs.s3.enabled=true,access_logs.s3.bucket=dev-ingress-logs-acme,access_logs.s3.prefix=dev-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    ....
    - host: entity-extractor.staging.<redacted>
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: entity-extractor-api-staging
                port:
                  number: 80
```

**example alb log**

```
type | time | elb | client_ip | client_port | target_ip | target_port | request_processing_time | target_processing_time | response_processing_time | elb_status_code | target_status_code | received_bytes | sent_bytes | request_verb | request_url | request_proto | user_agent | ssl_cipher | ssl_protocol | target_group_arn | trace_id | domain_name | chosen_cert_arn | matched_rule_priority | request_creation_time | actions_executed | redirect_url | lambda_error_reason | target_port_list | target_status_code_list | classification | classification_reason
-- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | --
https | 2021-10-06T14:36:19.995743Z | app/k8s-acme-78db7a121a/27d8ce64549c8574 | 148.252.239.114 | 52152 | 10.0.2.240 | 31037 | 0 | 0.001 | -1 | 502 | - | 481 | 272 | POST | https://entity-extractor.staging.<redacted<.com:443/ | HTTP/1.1 | axios/0.22.0 | ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 | TLSv1.2 | arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:700849607999:targetgroup/k8s-staging-entityex-1eaa7dc5fd/cfa1eeb14fd42a4c | Root=1-615db463-1042ab9118cc64b70f84b5a2 | entity-extractor.staging.<redacted>.com | arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:<redacted>:certificate/b32e9708-7aeb-495b-87b1-8532a2592eeb | 17 | 2021-10-06T14:36:19.901000Z | forward | - | - | 10.0.2.240:31037 | - | - | -
```

If there is any other information you need , please let me know.

Comment: Have you checked the target group metrics to see if its failing health checks on the load balancer side? The only thing that stands out to me as odd about this configuration is the services being NodePort instead of ClusterIP. ClusterIP is more typical when using an ingress as the ingress is what exposes the service to the outside.

Comment: yes i checked the target group under load balancer for this specific target and it is not failing the health check

Comment: Are the pods getting rescheduled?

Comment: You can see in the documentation of the alb https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.2/how-it-works/  under instance mode that services should be nodeports

Comment: The pods are not getting rescheduled, they have been alive for a number of days

Comment: Yeah, I see the nodeport requirement makes sense because the ingress lives outside of the cluster.

Comment: 502 can also be caused by an invalid response from your backend: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/load-balancer-http-502-errors/

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear earlier i am using an application load balancer not the classic load balancer. It is interesting if tahts still the case for ALB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-502-issues you're right it still says `The target response is malformed or contains HTTP headers that are not valid.`

But when i have received a 502, ive repeated the same request (payload) and received 200. So im not sure why the backend would be sending an invalid response the first time but success the second time.

Comment: The reason why i don't think its a malformed backend response is because i never see the initial request log. (i have seperated request and response logs with corresponding correlation id, and have setup a client http making requests with a header that i log and whenever there is a 502, i never see a log matching what the client sent.

Comment: I am having this issue now. But instead of 10-20% of the requests,  it's every other request for me approximately 50%. By any chance, have you found a solution? A walk-around perhaps?

Comment: @kglm look into the timeout values for  both the alb and your web server,  the alb maybe timing out (closing connection) before the web server can respond or visa-versa. cheeck your web servers timeout aswell

Comment: @Kay Appreciate your response. I will look into it tomorrow. Just to make sure, is this what you mean by time out on the alb?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

Answer (score 0):

Check if your service is listening on `0.0.0.0` for IPv4 or `::` for IPv6 instead of `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. Got this error with my IPv6-only AWS EKS cluster when I forgot to change my service's listening interface from `localhost` to `::` (`0.0.0.0` if you're using IPv4).